# Diferenças linhas do xml Android (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Galera, no curso que eu faço de Android ele trabalha na plataforma Eclipse(Versão antiga) e eu na versão mais recente, quando o professor utiliza o comando: `android.id` no dele da tudo certo, porém se eu digito essa linha ocorre um erro, tenho que usar o `android:id` para o comando funcionar, alguém pode me explicar?

E quando ele digita por ex: `android:id="@+calcular/botao1` da erro na minha linha, porém no dele não, mas se eu digito `android:id="@+id/botao1` ai sim consigo compilar.

Alguém me ajuda fazendo favor, Obrigado!

Comment: Qual erro apresenta @DaniloAlbergardi

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa posto  o erro

Comment: `android:id="@+id/linhameta"` exemplo tirado de um layout meu, pode explica o que é esse `android:id="@+calcular/botao1` calular?

Comment: se eu escrevo calcular(ou qualquer outra palavra) ao invés de id da erro

Comment: Consegui entender, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Qual é a versão da API do Android que ele está a usar e qual a sua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Android-Studio está atualizado para a melhor performance dos aplicativos Android.

Segundo a Google Developer, no Android Studio deve-se deixar `@+id/` e logo de seguida colocar o nome desejado do componente, exemplo - `@+id/botao1`.

Pois antigamente como no **Eclipse**, deixava-se usar `@+calcular/botao1`, mas viu-se que isso podia trazer problemas pois o Android agora quer tratar `@+id` como um todo e se fosse string `@+calcular` poderia futuramente dar problemas na aplicação.

O conselho que eles dão para deixar mais distinto, é usar um prefixo como por exemplo:

```
@+id/calcular_botao1
```

Sendo assim `@+id/` será tratado como um todo quando o Android compilar a app evitando erros que poderiam acontecer se fosse uma string (`@+calcaular/`).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Consegui entender, obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: A respeito do android.id ou android:id o eclipse antigo ainda não tratava esse erro, apenas quando era testada a aplicação ele aparecia!

Comment: Só uma coisa não era o Eclipse que deixava usar `@+calcular/botao1` era mesmo a API do Android. Entretanto é como Alysson diz, use prefixo.

Comment: Nada tem a ver com o Eclipse... É da API (sdk) do Android o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade deve-se usar:

```
android:id="@+id/id_do_componente"
```

Nunca estudei muito a fundo o Eclipse antigo, mas sei que o código era usado assim desta maneira.

Comment: Entendi, porém não vai ficar tudo desorganizado dentro do "id"? porque no código dele quando ele vai chamar no java fica tudo agrupado, ex: tudo que envolve o botão calcular fica no grupo calcular **android:id="@+calcular/id_do_componente"** ai o id_do_componente são os subgrupos que são criados

Comment: Pode ate ficar desorganizado, oque um pouco de empenho nao ajude, mas vai funcionar

Comment: Consegui entender, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

Para atribuir `id's` em seus componentes utilize a forma abaixo:

```
<TextView   android:id="@+id/textTituloGrupo"/>
```

Na sua `Activity` ficaria algo assim:

```
 private TextView               textTituloGrupo;    

textTituloGrupo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTituloGrupo);
```

Pelo seu comentário você poderia ter um método `calcularbotao();` para organizar seu código.

[Neste link você pode olhar outras convenções](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Consegui entender, obrigado pela atenção!